# System command to remove characters from a column in raw text file

Tags: linux, r, sed

I have a comma separated text file where one of the variables isn't in a great format because it itself contains commas (variable2, example below)

I'm hoping that I can just tidy the file, using system commands, by deleting the contents of the variable before "###" which is present on each line (without affecting the variables before the one in question)

Current format:

```
variable1   variable2   variable3   variable4   variable5               variable6
1           aaa         1           1           Milcek K1 2D            Milcek###Bel Ami
1           bbb         2           2           Milcek K1 2D            Milcek###Bel Ami
2           aaa         3           3           Koupili jsme zoo K1 2D  Koupili jsme Zoo###We Bought a Zoo
2           bbb         4           4           Koupili jsme zoo K1 2D  Koupili jsme Zoo###We Bought a Zoo
3           aaa         5           5           Koupili jsme zoo K1 2D  Koupili jsme Zoo###We Bought a Zoo
4           bbb         6           6           Titanic 3D K1           Titanic###Titanic
5           aaa         7           7           Snehurka K1 2D          Snehurka###Mirror Mirror
5           bbb         8           8           Snehurka K1 2D          Snehurka###Mirror Mirror
5           aaa         9           9           Snehurka K1 2D          Snehurka###Mirror Mirror
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let reformat file, since space also is included in fields. Replace more then 2 spaces with some unused symbol, for CSV like , (can be change if needed)

```
sed -r 's/  +/,/g' file
```

then making replacements

```
sed -r 's/,[^,]*###/,/' file
```

and finally replacing , with let say 10 space

```
sed 's/,/          /g'
```

or put it all together with piping

```
sed -r 's/  +/,/g' file | sed -r 's/,[^,]*###/,/' | sed 's/,/          /g' > output
```

It seems from provided input that best will be to avoid last step and leave , to separate fields. Or to use awk with printf function for better format (provided from some of awk experts), or even you can try with little awk research.

Comment: It may be helpful to append `| column -t`.

Comment: thanks for the replies, I've tried the command sed -r 's/( +)[^#]+###/\1/' file.txt > file_clean.txt
but it seems to be deleting data from the previous column and in other cases other columns before that. Perhaps it could be due to a difference in the test data format that i provided to the actual format, any thoughts? thanks

Comment: yes, all possible inputs should be provided for global solution.